# Format number as currency in Oracle Case Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I just started using Oracle and I need some help. I am building a query using case statements to pivot a column and sum on that but I don't know how, or where, to add formatting in my syntax. Here is my query:

```
select CONTRACTDATE,

sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='NAID' then noteopenamt end) as NAID,
sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='UAID' then noteopenamt end) as UAID,
sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='RVID' then noteopenamt end) as RVID,
sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='MAID' then noteopenamt end) as MAID,
sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='MCID' then noteopenamt end) as MCID
```

I'm pretty sure I need to add TO_CHAR(noteopenamt,'$9,999.99') somewhere, but do I add that after SUM or do I add that before noteopenamt after "THEN"?

Comment: `to_char(sum(case...),$9,999.99)`  you want to keep the value a number while it sums, then when sum is complete cast it to the desired format.  note this will only return a max 9,999.99 value!  alternatively keep it a number and handle the formatting in the presentation layer.

Comment: It would be pretty simple to try to both ways, wouldn't it? And then to see that doing either would cause the `sum()` to error with ORA-01722... you need to format the *result* of the sum, as xQbert showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you try either of the two things you were considering, with code like this 'after the sum':

```
sum (to_char (case when currmiaccttypcd='NAID' then noteopenamt end, '$9,999.99')) as NAID,
```

or like this 'after the then'

```
sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='NAID' then to_char (noteopenamt, '$9,999.99') end) as NAID,
```

then you will get an "ORA-01722: invalid number" exception. Either way you are converting your number to a string, and then trying to sum those strings. As `sum()` expects a numeric argument, it tries to implicitly convert your string back to a number; and something of the form `to_number('$42.00')` will get that ORA-01722 error because the $ sign isn't recognised as part of a number format.

Instead you need to sum the numbers and then convert the result to a string:

```
to_char (sum (case when currmiaccttypcd='NAID' then noteopenamt end), '$9,999.99') as NAID,
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that worked perfectly. In the end I am going to take @xQbert's suggestion and do the final formatting in the presentation layer. Nonetheless, I will surely need to use this in the future.

Comment: @RonL - you may have only started with Oracle, but you already understood a fundamental concept that seems alien to many long-time developers: formatting is best done in the presentation layer!  While it does help to know how to do things in SQL, for certain jobs (including formatting of final results) the SQL tricks should be the last thing one tries, not the first.